# Can a clustered index survive being moved to a different tablespace?

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, clustered-index

I have a table that is initially partitioned by day. At the end of every day no more records will be added to that partition, so I cluster the index and then I then do a lot of number crunching and aggregation on that table (using the index I clustered):

```
CLUSTER table_a_20181104 USING table_a_20181104_index1;
```

After a few days (typically a week) I merge the partition for one day into a larger partition that contains all the days data for that month. I use this SQL to achieve this:

```
WITH moved_rows AS 
( 
    DELETE FROM table_a_20181104 
    RETURNING * 
) 
INSERT INTO table_a_201811 
SELECT * FROM moved_rows;
```

After maybe a month or too I change the tablespace to move the data from an SSD disk to a conventional magnetic hard disk.

```
ALTER TABLE ... SET TABLESPACE ...
```

My initial clustering of the index at the end of the day definitely improves the performance of the queries run against it.

I know that clustering is a one-off command and needs to be repeated if new records are added/removed.

My questions are:

- Do I need to repeat the clustering after merging the 'day' partition into the 'month' partition?
- Do I need to repeat the clustering after altering the tablespace?
- Do I need to repeat the clustering if I `VACUUM` the partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Moving the data from one partition to the other will destroy the clustering, so you'll need to re-cluster after it.
- `ALTER TABLE ... SET TABLESPACE` will just copy the table files as they are, so clustering will be preserved.
- `VACUUM` does not move the rows, so clustering will also be preserved.